# Detecting a disconnection from SSE on ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, server-sent-events, .net-core

I want to detect a disconnection from SSE (Server Send Events) on ASP.NET Core. Old way `Response.IsClientConnected` not working. Do you have solution for this problem?

Answer (score 9):

I found temporary solution to my question. Temporary because `IsCancellationRequested` is detected when trying to send request and it failed, not when user disconnected before send request

```
if (HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested == true)
{
     break;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Please comment if you ever find out a "correct" way.

Answer (score 4):

**In .NET Core 2.0:**

This method creates an endpoint that will return `null` after 60 seconds. If the request is cancelled during those 60 seconds the method will return `null` immediately.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> Get()
{
    Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted.WaitHandle.WaitOne(60000);
    return null;
}
```

This method does multiple units of work while the request is connected and until the work is completed.

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<Items[]> Get()
{
    Item item = null;
    List<Items> items = new List<Items>();
    do
    {
        item = DoRepitiousWork();
        Items.Add(item);
    }
    while (!Request.HttpContext.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested && !item.IsLast);
    return items.ToArray();
}
```